# Problem signing jars for web applet

Tags: java, jar, applet, jarsigner

1. keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias me
2. keytool -selfcert -keystore myKeyStore -alias me
3. jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore jarfile.jar me

I'm using this way to sign jars.
I use my jar and a few more as libraries and all of them are signed this way, still, when I open the browser I get the warning that there is signed and unsigned code. So this is confusing me... :/

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1430071/images/errormessage.png

Comment: Besides the other more specific advice, make sure the applet cache is flushed for each test.  To do that, get focus on the Java console and type 'x'.  An easy way around browser class caching is to do your initial launches with JWS only (free-floating - no browser involved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article [*Mixing Signed and Unsigned Code*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html), the section entitled [*Deploying Signed Applications and Applets Securely Without a Mixed Code Warning*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html#manifest) offers two alternatives available in Java SE 6 Update 19 and later.

Addendum: Use `jarsigner -verbose -verify` to see additional information about signature details.

Answer (score 0):

You're signing your code with a self-signed certificate. You need to get a code signing certificate from an actual CA (costs $$$) and sign your code with that instead.

Comment: The certificate that costs, doesn't prompt anything, a normal certificate, like the one I'm using, prompts the user to accept it. The problem here is that there is no prompt to accept my certificate, it's saying that it's not signed, when I just signed it.

Comment: You're right, I did not look at the message. Are ALL the jars signed? Try "jarsigner -verify" on all your files.

Comment: "jar verified." for every single jar file :(

Comment: Try setting "Trusted-Only: true" in your main manifest file and see if that makes a difference. Also, is there anything in the Java console? It may tell you what's giving you a problem. There must be a sandboxed component somewhere.